# How to process environmental data for the input in MaxEnt (or any other modelling platform)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelling, maxent, environment-variable

I have downloaded some environmental rasters from Worldclim. Now, I want to generate an environmental layer for MaxEnt by applying conditions on those rasters. These rasters are 32 bit, floating point and do not have an attribute table either. I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [A Brief Tutorial on Maxent](https://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/maxent/Maxent_tutorial2017.pdf):

[image]

> The directory “layers” contains a number of ascii raster grids (in
> ESRI’s .asc format), each of which describes an environmental
> variable.  The grids must all have the same geographic bounds and cell
> size (i.e. all the ascii file headings must match each other
> perfectly).One of our variables, “ecoreg”,is a categorical variable
> describing potential vegetation classes.  The categories must be
> indicated by numbers, rather than letters or words.  You must tell the
> program which variables are categorical, as has been done in the
> picture above.

---

Taking this into account, you have to:

- Convert the WorldClim rasters (which are GeoTIFF files) to ascii raster grids.
- Make sure the rasters have the same extent and resolution.
- Crop the rasters to your area of interest (optional).

All this can be done using ArcGIS Desktop (which I assume by your tag is the program you are planning to use). I encourage you to read the tutorial as it gives a detailed explanation of Maxent's expected inputs and outputs.